# php regular expression help

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, lightbox

I'm adding shadow to images with a plugin and also using lightbox on the same site. This is the function in the wordpress plugin I'm editing:

```
function filter($content) {
return preg_replace_callback('#<img.+?src\s*=\s*["|\'](.+?)["|\'].+?>#isu', array($this, 'filter_callback'), $content);
}
```

And what it does is add a filter to all images and the filter adds shadow. But I don't want it to add the filter to ALL images. Because when it does, it somehow screws up lightbox. So I want to edit this line above to make sure that only if it's in a particular div or page to use the filter. Or another way might be to NOT filter if it's in a particular div or page.

I'd be happy to get a some kind of tutorial on how these regular expressions can be edited too.

Comment: You should really look into using an xml parser for this.

Comment: Yeah, really, use SimpleXML or something.

Comment: re: adding shadows to image - you know you can do this in CSS, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you alter the callback function too, it's not possible to do as you describe with a regex because:

1. flexible length lookbehinds are not allowed in PHP
2. doing as you describe while avoiding a flexible length lookbehind would change the value sent to the callback function

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for. But not the solution :) Now I'll check other people's answers to solve my issue.

Answer (score 6):

I know it won't work everywhere, but why don't you just use CSS3 [box-shadow](http://www.css3.info/preview/box-shadow/)?

Comment: Maybe not *everywhere*, but it will work in all browsers in common use these days -- even IE6/7/8 can do `box-shadow`, if you use [CSS3Pie](http://www.css3pie.com/).

Comment: Well, I got my answer to the question from someone else but the solution was this. Thanks to all. I can't believe how I didn't think about CSS3 to begin with...

Answer (score 5):

If you're using a lightbox, that means you're relying on Javascript on your site.

Why don't you make the (very helpful) jump to jQuery and use jQuery's (very useful) selectors to do this.  Instead of regex-ing for some strange location, just do something like

`$('.lightbox-photo').addClass('filter')`

I know this isn't EXACTLY an answer to your question, but I think it's a more versatile solution.

Comment: Tried didn't work as the plugin that does the filter acts before the script I add. Don't ask how and why, it's too messy at this point :D Not worth digging that much to fix just this. I'll try the CSS3...